# Example of ring having no superficial element.

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a Noetherian local ring and $I$ be an ideal of $A$. An element $x\in I$ is said to be an $A$-superficial element if there exists a natural number $c$ such that $(I^{n+1}:x)\cap I^c=I^n$ for all $n\geq c$.

We know that if the residue field of a Noetherian local ring $R$ is infinite then all ideal $I$ of $R$ contain an $R$-superficial element. I want an example of a ring of finite residue field with no superficial element for an ideal $I$. This is very useful in commutative algebra. For example to reduce dimension and depth.

Comment: Could you include a definition of "superficial element"?  Based on 5 minutes trying to find a concise definition and not finding one, I think people would find it useful.

Comment: Let A be a Noetherian local ring and I be an ideal of A. x\in I is said to be A-superficial element if there exist natural number c such that (I^{n+1}:x)\cap I^c=I^n for all n\geq c. It has been proved that if residue field is infinite then there always exist A superficial element for all non zero ideal.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information! You should edit it into the question, not the comments. I have done it for you this time so you can see how to format such things. It is as easy as wrapping math in dollar signs.  Click the "edited" timestamp to see what was changed.

Comment: You can find such an example in Huneke and Swanson textbook on integral closure.

Comment: Are there any simple example other than that?